# How long between UK Tier 5 GAE visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, uk-visa

I'm currently in the UK on a Tier 5 Temporary work visa (Government Authorised Exchange). My sponsor has indicated that they want me to stay an extra year but I'm having problems with visa options as the scheme they are under only allows my visa to be for a maximum of 12 months (ie it will expire this January). A Tier 2 work visa is not an option unfortunately, nor do I have British ancestry.

Can I return home (Australian passport holder), get another 12-month certificate of sponsorship from them, and re-apply for another Tier 5 GAE visa straight away? Or is there a minimum time I have to wait between work visas?

Comment: Would the Tier 5 (Youth Mobility) visa be an option for you?

Comment: @Nicole M What scheme is your visa under https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-n-authorised-exchange-schemes and what does your sponsor advise about the possibility of a second sponsorship? What is the justification for your sponsor wanting you to stay longer than their authorised scheme?

Comment: @B.Liu Unfortunately no, I'm too old for that visa

Comment: @Traveller I'm under the work experience scheme. A second sponsorship is guaranteed so long as I can get the visa and right to work in the UK. It seems my sponsor originally received the wrong advice on what scheme they were under and thought I could get the full 2 years. It's only come to light now that this was incorrect. I suspect there's nothing I can do though

Comment: Hi I'm Sarah on 26 july I had sent the evidence new photo for my visa, when I receive the acceptence email?